# draw circle on top of an image

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular (and web development on top of that) and I am working on a demo for a project. The idea is the user will upload an image and then they can draw some simple circles on the image wherever the user clicks. I used ng-flow and managed to get the upload to work. However when I try to draw a circle via svgs I see nothing. It seems to be an issue of order of the 'z' coordinate. Basically I can get either the image to show or the circles but not both. Is there a way in angular to draw on top of an element?

Comment: Any chance you could post your current code?

Comment: You could create a custom directive to do this.

Comment: Did you get the solution? If yes Could you Please post it ... @Pinsickle . Because I have same problem domain . I have x-ray image (Patient's x-ray image) . I need to draw , write and etc... on or Over the x-ray image ..

Comment: @sakthi Sorry but I don't have the code. I switched jobs since then and no longer have access to the code base. You can look at http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/lhajz and that may get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pinsickle